# Close qttab widget When clicking close button

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I have qtabwiget with one qwidget and the problem is when i click the close button of the setclosable func. the qwidget is not closed as well so how i close them as well? BElow is the part of closing the tab:

```
self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 75, self.sizeObject.width(), self.sizeObject.height() - 120))
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
    self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
    self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeMyTab)

def closeMyTab(self, tab):
    self.tabWidget.removeTab(tab)
```

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: I don't have complete example. I am just asking how i can delete/remove wigdet from tab before removing it.

Comment: Please explain better..unable to understand your query

Comment: Removing tab doesn't terminate the contents widgets that the tab contains .So, I am wondering if there is a way to delete those wigdets before removing tab.

Comment: `self.tabWidget.widget(tab).deleteLater()`.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what i wanted.